# read data to numpy array

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, int

I have a file below

```
label,feature
0,70 80 90 50 33 58 ...
2,53 56 84 56 25 12 ...
1,32 56 84 89 65 87 ...
...
2,56 48 57 56 99 22 ...
4,25 65 84 54 54 15 ...
```

I want the data could be

```
Ytrain = [0,2,1,...2,4]  (int, ndarray)
Xtrain = [[70 80 90 50 33 58...],
          [53 56 80 56 25 12...],
          ...
          [25 65 84 54 54 15...]] (int, ndarray)
```

here is my code

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
Ytrain = np.array(data.iloc[:, 0]).astype(int)
train = np.array(data.iloc[:, 1:]).astype(str)

Xtrain = []
for i in range(len(train)):
    tmp = [int(x) for x in train[i][0].split()]
    Xtrain.append(tmp)
Xtrain = np.array(Xtrain)
```

do you have a better way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add multiple separator to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `header=None` and `skiprows=1` for not read csv header:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', sep="[,\s+]", header=None, skiprows=1, engine='python')
print (data)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0  0  70  80  90  50  33  58
1  2  53  56  84  56  25  12
2  1  32  56  84  89  65  87
3  2  56  48  57  56  99  22
4  4  25  65  84  54  54  15
```

Last select by `iloc`:

```
Ytrain = data.iloc[:,0].values
Xtrain = data.iloc[:,1:].values
```

---

Or use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
Ytrain = data.iloc[:,0].values.astype(int)
Xtrain = data.iloc[:,1].str.split(expand=True).values.astype(int)

print (Ytrain)
[0 2 1 2 4]

print (Xtrain)
[[70 80 90 50 33 58]
 [53 56 84 56 25 12]
 [32 56 84 89 65 87]
 [56 48 57 56 99 22]
 [25 65 84 54 54 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` for this. Since you have multiple delimiters, a little more work is required.

```
import numpy as np

s = open('train.csv', 'r').read().replace(',', ' ')
arr = np.genfromtxt(s)

Ytrain = arr[:, 1]
Xtrain = arr[:, 1:]
```

Comment: @Sam, updated - play around / google with `open`, it should be possible to feed this into `genfromtxt`.